# Android event trigger when data is sent over network. Detect network use

Tags: java, android, events, networking

Is there any event that I could set a filter to pick up using a broadcast receiver that is triggered when data is being sent over the network?

What I would like to do, is sit idle until the user sends data over their wifi and then trigger do some processing.

I know about trafficStats and I will likely use it, but I can't seam to find any events that trigger when data is being sent over the network.  I've thought about polling using trafficstats to detect changes in tx/rx but that seams like a cumbersome method.  I have some other ideas, but I'm hoping there is a simple answer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know only how to listen for 3G network, in this case you can use TelephonyManager

```
TelephonyManager mTelmgr = (TelephonyManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mTelmgr.listen(mPhoneCallListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY);
```

However, this will not work for WiFi, where only polling I can think of.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I ended up using polling inside of a separate thread. This method works, doesn't tie up the UI thread, and is pretty light weight. Thanks for the help.